# Problems with res.cookie but not with res.json

Tags: angular, express, cookies

When I use `res.json()` in my Express `POST` route response, everything works fine. When I change the response to `res.cookie()`, I encounter `MongoDB 11000 Dup Key Error`, with the following strange behavior:

1. The Document saves correctly to MongoDB, but the `POST` XHR call seems to have problems as the browser console shows `POST . . . - - ms`, whereas normally it shows a number in milliseconds, i.e. `POST . . . -32 ms` (even though it still shows a `200` code).
2. A little while later, after a delay, I then get `Dup Key Error` as the route seems to try to save the Document a second time.

I have no other console errors on either front or back end and based on the console log, the contents of the cookie seem to be OK.

What could be going on?

**TEMPLATE**

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="doSignUp(f)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let key of keyArr; index as i"> 

    <label [hidden]='key[1]'> {{key[2]}}
      <div>
          <input *ngIf="key[1]==='password' type='password' [formControlName]='key[0]' id={{key[0]}} name={{key[0]}}/>
          <input *ngIf="key[1]!=='password' type='text' [formControlName]='key[0]' id={{key[0]}} name={{key[0]}}/>
      </div>
     </label>
    <br/>

    </ng-container>
    <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
doSignUp(f: NgForm) {
  this.member.postSignupForm(f).subscribe((res)=>console.log(`RES: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`));
}
```

**AUTH SERVICE (MEMBER SERVICE)**

```
postSignupForm(f: NgForm): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.signup_url, f.value);
}
```

**EXPRESS `POST` ROUTE (https://localhost:3000/users/sign-up)**

```
 . . . 
 . . . 
 user.save().then(()=> {
    res.json({"foo": "bar"} // EVERYTHING WORKS FINE. 
// IF, INSTEAD of res.json() I USE: res.cookie("SESSIONID", user.generateJWT(), {httpOnly:true, secure:true}); 
// then I get MONGODB DUP KEY ERROR as either front-end or back-end tries to save the same record a second time.
```

**COOKIE MIDDLEWARE**

```
UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {
    const today = new Date();
    const expirationDate = new Date(today);
    expirationDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

    const thisJwt = jwt.sign({
        email: this["authData"].mainEmail.value[this["authData"].mainEmail.value.length-1],
        id: this._id,
        exp: parseInt(expirationDate.getTime() / 1000, 10),
    }, 'secret');
    console.log(`TOKEN: ${JSON.stringify(thisJwt)}`);
    return thisJwt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In back-end, after res.cookie(), I needed to add res.send('done').

```
 user.save().then(()=> {
    res.cookie("SESSIONID", user.generateJWT(), {httpOnly:true, secure:true});
    res.send('done');
 }
```

In front-end, I needed to add `responseType` to the `POST` call:

```
postSignupForm(f: NgForm): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.signup_url, f.value, {responseType: 'text'});
}
```